# Assert package call directions with AspectJ

Tags: java, testing, architecture, automated-tests, aspectj

let's assume I have the following package structure

```
some.package
    |-aaa.private
    |-aaa.public
    |-bbb.private
    |-bbb.public
```

My architecture would demand, that I only make calls from `some.package.aaa..*` to `some.package.bbb.public..*` and vice versa, only calls from `some.package.bbb..*` to `some.package.aaa.public..*`. In other words, if I traverse the "major" package border (e.g. from aaa to bbb), I only want to allow calls to the public package in the root of the other major package.

Is it possible to define an AspectJ Pointcut, which selects all Joinpoints that violate this rule? I.e. if I want to write

```
declare error: inSomeMajorPackage() && callingNonPublicPackageOfOtherMajorPackage() :
    "Please make calls only to public interfaces of other major packages";
```

Is there any way to define those two Pointcuts, such that they enforce this rule?

Comment: A question before I start thinking about it: Do you really want to match package names? Why not just use public and non-public methods? If methods in other packages are not visible outside the package, they cannot be called from outside in the first place.

Comment: The problem is, that it might be more complex, having different subpackages under aaa.private, etc. And then unfortunately package private is not good enough, because you can't access classes in a subpackage... aaa and bbb should be considered modules with bigger complexity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attention:** This will be a lengthy answer because of the code samples.

I created a sample project which can be downloaded from [Scrum-Master.de](http://scrum-master.de/download/StackOverflow/SO_AJ_PackageTraversalRestrictions.zip). The package structure is as follows:

[image: Package structure]

As you can see, below the main application package **de.scrum_master** there are three "major" packages *common*, *feature1*, *feature2*, each containing sub-packages *pub* (public) and *prv* (private). Additionally there is an *aop* package containing all aspects. Each *pub/prv* sub-package contains a dummy class.

The Java classes are as follows:

```java
package de.scrum_master.common.pub;

import de.scrum_master.common.prv.CommonPrivate;
import de.scrum_master.feature1.prv.Feature1Private;
import de.scrum_master.feature1.pub.Feature1Public;
import de.scrum_master.feature2.prv.Feature2Private;
import de.scrum_master.feature2.pub.Feature2Public;

public class Application {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Application(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Application    (1, "Application"));
        System.out.println(new CommonPrivate  (2, "Common (private)"));
        System.out.println(new Feature1Public (3, "Feature 1 (public)"));
        System.out.println(new Feature1Private(4, "Feature 1 (private)"));
        System.out.println(new Feature2Public (5, "Feature 2 (public)"));
        System.out.println(new Feature2Private(6, "Feature 2 (private)"));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Application [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.common.prv;

public class CommonPrivate {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public CommonPrivate(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CommonPrivate [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.feature1.pub;

public class Feature1Public {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Feature1Public(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Feature1Public [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.feature1.prv;

import de.scrum_master.feature2.prv.Feature2Private;
import de.scrum_master.feature2.pub.Feature2Public;

public class Feature1Private {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Feature1Private(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        new Feature2Private(11111, "This should be illegal");
        new Feature2Public(22222, "This should be OK");
        return "Feature1Private [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.feature2.pub;

public class Feature2Public {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Feature2Public(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Feature2Public [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.feature2.prv;

import de.scrum_master.feature1.prv.Feature1Private;
import de.scrum_master.feature1.pub.Feature1Public;

public class Feature2Private {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Feature2Private(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        new Feature1Private(33333, "This should be illegal");
        new Feature1Public(44444, "This should be OK");
        return "Feature2Private [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Now we need our aspect. More exactly, we need an abstract base aspect and one package-specific concrete sub-aspect for each "major" package. This is not nice, but it works.

The abstract base aspect looks like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

public abstract aspect AccessController {
    // All method/constructor calls to base package
    pointcut basePackageCall():
        call(* de.scrum_master..*.*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master..*.new(..));

    // Method/constructor calls to public packages
    pointcut publicPackageCall() :
        call(* de.scrum_master..*.pub..*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master..*.pub..new(..));

    // Own "major" package. Please override in concrete sub-aspect like this:
    // within(de.scrum_master.mymajor..*) 
    pointcut ownPackage();

    // Method/constructor calls within own "major" package. Please override in concrete sub-aspect like this:
    // call(* de.scrum_master.mymajor..*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master.mymajor..new(..)) 
    pointcut ownPackageCall();

    pointcut forbiddenCall() :
        ownPackage() && basePackageCall() && !(publicPackageCall() || ownPackageCall());

    declare error: forbiddenCall() :
        "Illegal call to non-public foreign major package";
}
```

As you can see there are two pointcuts which must be concretised by the sub-aspects like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

public aspect AccessController_Common extends AccessController {
    pointcut ownPackage() :
        within(de.scrum_master.common..*);

    pointcut ownPackageCall() :
        call(* de.scrum_master.common..*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master.common..new(..));
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

public aspect AccessController_Feature1 extends AccessController {
    pointcut ownPackage() :
        within(de.scrum_master.feature1..*);

    pointcut ownPackageCall() :
        call(* de.scrum_master.feature1..*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master.feature1..new(..));
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

public aspect AccessController_Feature2 extends AccessController {
    pointcut ownPackage() :
        within(de.scrum_master.feature2..*);

    pointcut ownPackageCall() :
        call(* de.scrum_master.feature2..*(..)) || call(de.scrum_master.feature2..new(..));
}
```

Creating sub-aspects for new "major" packages is as simple as copy & paste plus minor editing for the corresponding package name.

If you inspect `Application.main`, `Feature1Private.toString` and `Feature2Private.toString` you will see that I built in some illegal calls to non-public foreign sub-packages there, four all in all. It looks like this in Eclipse's problem view:

[image]

A few more words about the base/sub aspects: While in an advice it is possible to dynamically determine package names and do some more magic via reflection, `declare error` is based on pointcuts which can be determined statically during compile time. Thus, we must be more specific and explicit here which requires us to have one sub-aspect for each "major" package in your scenario. The alternative would be one big concrete aspect containing pointcuts for each single package. I thought this would look ugly though.

Now enjoy my solution, I think it adequately addresses your problem. `:-)`

Comment: Thanks for your effort!!! This indeed solves my example from above :-) The only problem is, that this doesn't seem to scale well, if I have something like 100 modules? Because then I need 100 aspects, which I had hoped to avoid. On the other hand, at least it's modular and new modules can be added without changing the existing aspects... I guess due to the statical nature of the declare syntax, it is not possible to solve this in a more generic manner?

Comment: Since there are no generic ideas, I'm marking this idea as solution, since it's the way I'm following now, even though I need one subaspect per module :-)
Thank you four your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to enforce or discourage certain package dependencies, you can use a different approach using JDepend. Please see this [blog post](http://digitalbrikes.com/onebrikeatatime/2009/03/05/enforcing-package-dependencies-with-jdepend/) about how to do it, but it basically means you need to write a test such as

```
@Test
public void verifyDependencies() {
    thisPackage()
        .dependsOn("my.super.fantastic.package")
    .andOn("my.sortof.ok.package")
    .andItShouldNotDependOn("that.pesky.vendor.package")
    .orOn("my.very.bad.package");

    assertItHasAllAndNoOtherDependencies();
}
```

As you mentioned in a comment to another answer, this doesn't actually scale, but you can put the data in a CSV, excel or similar file and use the data to enforce the dependencies.

If you want to go commercial take a look at [Structure 101](http://structure101.com/products/), but I don't think it's worth the money.

And I forgot to say, that if you have cyclic dependencies between packages (aaa.public and bbb.public depending on each other) it means that you have a flaw in your design.